# Is there a way to convert a `Vec<Vec<T>>` to `Vec<T>`, combining all the `Vec<T>`s into one `Vec<T>`?

Tags: rust

Let's say I have a Vector of Organisation ids

```rust
let orgs = vec![1, 3, 14, 12];
```

I then call `.iter()` on each to get the events of each organisation, where the function `get_events_for()` returns `Vec<Event>`

```rust
let events = orgs
    .iter()
    .map(|org_id| {
        get_events_for(org_id)
    })
    .collect();
```

Currently, events is equal to `Vec<Vec<Event>>`, so how would one go about converting that to just `Vec<Event>`?

Comment: Use `flatten()` after map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what a more complete implementation would look like using some of the answers already given here:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Event {
    id: usize
}

fn main() {
  let orgs = vec![1, 3, 14, 12];

  let events: Vec<Event> = orgs
    .iter()
    .flat_map(|org_id| {
        get_events_for(*org_id)
    })
    .collect();

  println!("{:?}", events);

}

fn get_events_for(id: usize) -> Vec<Event> {
   vec![Event {id}]
}
```

The output would look like:

```rust
[Event { id: 1 }, Event { id: 3 }, Event { id: 14 }, Event { id: 12 }]
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a2c01231c3ef3ca7576db33b4c0f2e61)

Answer (score 3):

[`flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map):

```
let events = orgs
    .iter()
    .flat_map(get_events_for)
    .collect();
```